# From base class in C#, get derived type?

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, types

Let's say we've got these two classes:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string s)
        : base(s)
    { }
}

public class Base
{
    protected Base(string s)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I find out from within the constructor of `Base` that `Derived` is the invoker? This is what I came up with:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string s)
        : base(typeof(Derived), s)
    { }
}

public class Base
{
    protected Base(Type type, string s)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there another way that doesn't require passing `typeof(Derived)`, for example, some way of using reflection from within `Base`'s constructor?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b = new Base();
            Derived1 d1 = new Derived1();
            Derived2 d2 = new Derived2();
            Base d3 = new Derived1();
            Base d4 = new Derived2();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public Base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Constructor. Calling type: {0}", this.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    class Derived1 : Base { }
    class Derived2 : Base { }
}
```

This program outputs the following:

```
Base Constructor: Calling type: Base
Base Constructor: Calling type: Derived1
Base Constructor: Calling type: Derived2
Base Constructor: Calling type: Derived1
Base Constructor: Calling type: Derived2
```

Comment: A better example would be to show the output of `Derived1 d1 = new Base();`

Comment: `Derived1 d1 = new Base();` generates a compile-time error, you probably mean the other way around. FYI `((Base)new Derived1()).GetType().Name` is "Derived1"

Answer (score 43):

[`GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype) would give you what you're looking for.