# xUnit.net Class Fixture needs name of test class about to run

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have a project where multiple test classes share a base class fixture.

As expected, the fixture's constructor runs before any test in the test class is run.

Is there a way for this class fixture's constructor to know the name of the test class that is about to run?

Background: My project is not doing unit testing, but rather I'm using xUnit.net to run an alternate type of testing.  All the classes and tests will run in order, so a class is guaranteed to run completely before another class tries to run.

Here is an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```cs
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace TestingProject
{
    // In my project, the classes are guaranteed to run in order, one after the other.  Tests won't randomly execute between classes.
    // This fixture is used by multiple test classes.  It handles logging test class starts and stops to the db.
    public class SharedTestingClassFixture : IDisposable
    {
        // This will run at the start of every testing class.
        public SharedTestingClassFixture()
        {
            // Need to get name of class that is about to execute, i.e. "TestingClassName"
            var nameOfTestingClass = "";

            // Log name of class that is about to start to the db BEFORE any tests run.
            var logMessage = $"{nameOfTestingClass} class starting";
        }

        // This will run at the end of every testing class.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Log class ending to db after all tests in this class have finished.
        }
    }

    public class TestingClassName : TestClassBase, IDisposable, IClassFixture<SharedTestingClassFixture>
    {
        // This will run before each individual test.
        public TestingClassName(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper) : base(testOutputHelper)
        {
            // At this point, I need to already have written the class name to the db; BEFORE this constructor is called.
            // The TestClassBase (not shown) constructor then extracts the test name from testOutputHelper and logs to db.
        }

        // This will run after each individual test.
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Testing code here
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            // Testing code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: per https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context the way to ensure multiple concrete instances dont run at same time, you want to use a collection fixture. You might get predictable order in which class runs first. You should not get predictable order of tests within a given concrete class. As you know, the problem with that is that the fixture is only made/destroyed once. If you had a collection _and_ a class fixture, you'd get a fresh fixture per concrete class. To find out the concrete type, just use GetType (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/972535/11635). Any of this any use?

Comment: @RubenBartelink, thanks for the quick reply! I actually am using both a collection and class fixture in my actual project.  Using some xUnit.net sample code from [xUnit](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/TestOrderExamples) my project is currently able to execute tests grouped together in order.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to get the test class name (of the class which is about to run) in the class fixture that runs before each test class.  I tried using GetType().Name, but that is returning the name of the fixture itself, not the test class.

Comment: Perhaps, If you wrap the logic inside the fixture inside a `Lazy<T>`, you might be able to have the user call `fixture.Initialize(this)` in the consuming ctor and then have that (perhaps async) trigger the initialization. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure xUnit has no intrinsic way to pick up the prosepctive 'owner' of a ClassFixture in its constructor as it seems you're looking for..

Comment: I was afraid that xUnit might not have this ability.  Thank you for the suggestion of an alternate approach, @RubenBartelink.